# Google Classroom - Get Course by Alias

Tags: c#, google-api, google-classroom

I'm trying to get a Google Classroom Course in C# using its **[Project Alias](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-courses)**.

On the API Documentation page I can get the course no problem using ID or Alias.
For talking sake, let's say:

ID - 123456 
Alias - p:abc

When I try on the [Documentation page](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/get) I get a 200 response and retrieve the course when I use either of the above.
However, when in code I can only get the course using the ID. When I try to do it using the alias I get the following error: 404 course not found.

```
 var id= "123456";
 var alias = "p:abc";

 var request = classroomService.Courses.Get (id);
 var course = request.Execute(); //200 response, course is the JSON course

 request = classroomService.Courses.Get(alias);
 course = request.Execute(); //404 - COURSE NOT FOUND
```

Not sure if I have to somehow specify the request is using a project-alias but I can't seem to see any options within the request to suggest this.

Thanks

**EDIT**: Just to add to this, I have tested using a domain alias,
alias - "d:xyz"

This works fine in code, so it appears it is just the project wide alias that isn't working.

Comment: Did you create the alias for your classroom from the same C# app?

Comment: I had initially but I had created a few via the documentation page to test and therefore these would be associated with a different project id... doh! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.aliases) says, project aliases are visible only by the same project id that created them.

> A project-scoped alias is visible to any request from an application using the Developer Console project ID that created the alias and can be created by any project.

Since the project ID used to create the aliases is different from the one used to call the `.get()` method it will return a `404 - Course Not Found` error.